# How schedule nightly email of TFS query

Tags: report

I have a TFS 2010 query I wrote. From web portal I can run query then select "Email all work items as a list" from the Tools menu. This email is perfect. Is there any way to get this scheduled to run daily?

Do I need to get it in as a report in SSRS? Can I convert a query to a report?